# How to get name of recently played song on FM radio station

Tags: fm-radio

FM radios (eg in the cars) show the name of songs actually played. So the car radio needs to get song's name from somewhere. Is there a way to get this data into database? Just asking generally cause I was thinking how to get this data (Radio Station's name, the name of song). What should I use to do it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System  Good luck

Comment: Marcin, any news? You neither downvoted my answer nor accepted it, so I was left to wonder if you still have questions

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ hey, sory i've forgotten to accept ur answer. I was just wondering how does work websites which allows you to see what song is playing right now on selected radio. You have to install a gr-rds on server or what?

Comment: Maybe they have a radio receiver somewhere, and use software to extract that info from the radio signal. More likely, they just have an agreement with the radio station, which just sends them this information over some internet technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the Radio Data System (RDS). Yes, you can get that information, if you have a receiver that pushes the "raw" signal as it comes through the air into your PC. You would then be doing Software Defined Radio (SDR).

It's not costly to get such a receiver, and Bastian Blössl has continued work on a decoder and transmitter, [gr-rds](https://github.com/bastibl/gr-rds) based on [GNU Radio](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials), an SDR processing framework. Great fun!